# Can the ParentForm's Settings property be accessed from a constituent user control, in order to modify such a setting?

Tags: .net, vb.net

It is not too difficult to make a Form's location persistent, so that it can be repositioned where it was on restart:

```
Private Sub FlatForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Location = My.Settings.Location
End Sub

Private Sub FlatForm_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LocationChanged
    My.Settings.Location = Location
End Sub

Private Sub FlatForm_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

However, I have a user control being placed on many of my apps, so I was thinking of intercepting the parent's according events, in order to automatically do this for them as a service.

For example for the `Disposed` event:

```
Private Sub MyUserControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler ParentForm.Disposed, AddressOf ParentDisposed
End Sub
```

But I have no clue on how to access the parent form's `Settings` property in the handler:

```
Private Sub ParentDisposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ?
End Sub
```

Surely I can not add `My.Settings.Save()`, because I do not want to save the user control's location, but the parent form's in its own folder.

Is this possible, or need I do this a completely different way?

Comment: It would be inappropriate for a user control to take on such a responsibility. It would be more appropriate to create a component whose specific purpose was to do that. If you aren't aware of it, research the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: `My.Settings.Location = ParentForm.Location`? -- FYI `My.Settings` _**is not**_ control-specific, but applies to the whole project. `My.Settings.Save()` merely writes all the settings to disk.

Comment: @VisualVincent, I was not aware of the non-control-specificy, thanks for this. Yes, it works. I will put my findings based on your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a comment by user Visual Vincent, this is a working solution.

If you have placed a user control on a Windows Form, you can have automatic form tracking including persistency between calls.

---

In the control's `Load` event, this property is retrieved and applied to the parent form. Note, that we are coding the control's event, not the client form's. This means, that the client form may already be shown (yes, even before the `Load` event finishes), depending on what you do in it. This means, that we should place the according code to the event's very top.

It might seem natural, that the parent's location should be updated and saved in the `Disposed` event, but upon arriving there, the reference to `ParentForm` is `Nothing` already. This is also true, if the parent's `Disposed` event is handled by the control via `AddHandler`. Instead, we must use the parent's intercepted `LocationChanged` event to track the form's movements and to keep our property up-to-date.

```
Private Sub MyControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles MyBase.Load

    'Retrieve the parent form's Location setting and apply it.
    ParentForm.Location = My.Settings.Location

    'Intercept the parent's LocationChanged event, so that its Location
    'property can be updated.
    AddHandler ParentForm.LocationChanged, AddressOf ParentLocationChanged

    ...
End Sub

'This routine is called, when the parent form is moved. It is intercepted in
'order to update the application's Location setting.
Private Sub ParentLocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    My.Settings.Location = ParentForm.Location
End Sub
```

It is in the control's `Dispose` event, in which the settings are stored, including the `Location` setting.

*You may want to opt out of this and have
the client **only** be saving its own settings.*

```
'When done, the application's settings are saved.
Private Sub MyControl_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles Me.Disposed

    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

From now on, when such a control is placed on a Form control, it automatically also monitors its movements and stores the form's position persistently between two sessions.

Comment: Just remember that you need a unique setting for each form, _**or**_ some sort of lookup table. :)

Answer (score 0):

the [`Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Property:

```
YourControle.Parent.Location
```